# How can I properly unwrap this mesh to fit this texture?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

Sorry if the question is vague but I don't know what other way to phrase it.
I've been working on a model for an eyeball and I've been using this model as a reference.
[image]

*Not mine! This is Alef itd's!*

I had a friend of mine redraw the texture for the retina, but I'm really unclear how to unwrap the mesh to make it match the texture. My mesh looks like this:
[image]

The reference I'm using unwrapped the model like this:
[image]

But I can't figure out where to put the seams to get this map.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: check this out that is my solution... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130285/how-do-i-wrap-this-label-on-cup/130286?noredirect=1#comment224548_130286

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I wrap this label on cup?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130285/how-do-i-wrap-this-label-on-cup)